# PROBLEMA AL MOSTRAR DATOS EN AJAX EN UNA TABLA HTML CON DATOS CONTENIDOS EN TRES TABLAS MYSQL QUE COMPARTEN LOS MISMOS CAMPOS

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Estoy intentando mostrar con Ajax los datos que resultan de una consulta mysql usando LEF JOIN ya que son tres tablas que tienen un valor en comun. Tengo la tabla DOCENTES, ALUMNOS y ACUDIENTES y estan relacionadas por el numero de documento de Identidad (CAMPO: numIdentidad). El caso es que en la consulta traigo el nombre del docente, nombre del alumno y nombre del empleado pero al mostrarlo en la tabla html solo puedo mostrar uno de los tres. si muestro las filas que contienen el nombre del alumno, las celda nombre de la fila donde estan los datos del docente se muestra vacia. Que puedo hacer??

ESTE ES EL SCRIPT QUE USO PARA LLENAR LA TABLA CON AJAX:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){


    function obtener_datos(){
        var caso_id = $('#caso_id').val();
    
    $.ajax({
        data: {caso_id:caso_id},
        dataType: 'json',
        url:'mostrarinvolucrados.php',
        method: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            
            var valor = '';
            var fechaEdad='';
  data.result.forEach(product => {
    fechaEdad=product.fechaNacimiento;
    //este procedimiento es para obtener la edad
    var fechaNacimiento = new Date(fechaEdad);
                    var fechaActual = new Date();
                    
                    // Calcula la diferencia de años
                    var edad = fechaActual.getFullYear() - fechaNacimiento.getFullYear();
                    
                    // Verifica si ya celebró su cumpleaños este año
                    if (fechaNacimiento.getMonth() > fechaActual.getMonth() ||
                        (fechaNacimiento.getMonth() === fechaActual.getMonth() && fechaNacimiento.getDate() > fechaActual.getDate())) {
                        edad--;
                    }

    
    valor += "<tr>"+

    // "<td>" + product.ID_involucrado + "</td>"+
    

    '<td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs borrar" value="Eliminar" /></td>' +
    //'<td><button class="btn btn-danger fa fa-trash"></button></button></td>' +
    //&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="btn btn-warning fa fa-pencil"></button></td>' +
    
    
    "<td>" + product.numIdentidad + "</td>"+
    "<td>" + $nombre + "</td>"+ "<td>" +
    "<td>" + product.primerApellido + "</td>"+
    "<td>" + product.segundoApellido + "</td>"+
    "<td>" + product.curso + "</td>"+
    "<td>" + edad + "</td>"+
    "<td>" + product.rol + "</td>"+
     "<td>" + product.condicion + "</td>"+ 
     //"<td>" + product.caso_id + "</td>"+
     "<tr>";
  });
      $("#result").html(valor);
    }
    

    });
}
```

Y ESTA ES LA CONSULTA QUE HAGO A LA BASE DE DATOS:

```
<?php
include("../../bd.php");

$data=array();


//WHERE a.numIdentidad={$_POST['numIdentidad']}");
$caso_id=$_POST["caso_id"];
 
           $consulta = $conexion->prepare("SELECT tbl_involucrados.numIdentidad,tbl_involucrados.condicion,
           d.primerNombre AS nombreD,d.primerApellido AS apellidoPD,d.segundoApellido AS apellidoMD,d.rol AS rolD,d.telefono AS telefonoD,
           a.primerNombre,a.primerApellido,a.segundoApellido,a.fechaNacimiento,a.curso,a.rol,
           p.primerNombre AS nombreP,p.primerApellido AS apellidoPP,p.segundoApellido AS apellidoMP,p.rol AS rolP,p.telefono AS telefonoP
           FROM tbl_involucrados
              LEFT OUTER JOIN 
              tbl_docentes AS d
              ON tbl_involucrados.numIdentidad=d.numIdentidad
              
              LEFT OUTER JOIN
              tbl_alumnos AS a
              ON tbl_involucrados.numIdentidad=a.numIdentidad 

              LEFT OUTER JOIN
              tbl_acudientes AS p
              ON tbl_involucrados.numIdentidad=p.numIdentidad 
      
            WHERE tbl_involucrados.caso_id='87' 
           ");

$consulta->execute();
$result = $consulta->fetchAll (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if ($result)
  {
  
  $data['status']='ok';
  $data['result']=$result;
  $data["success"] = true;

  }else{
    $data['status']='err';
    $data['result']='';
    $data["success"] = false;
  }

        
header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode($data,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

$conexion=null;

?>
```

Comment: Buenas, Jesús, bienvenido al sitio. Creo que uno de los problemas está en la operación que usas para combinar las tablas. A LEFT OUTER JOIN B te incluye todos los registros de A siempre, incluyendo aquellos que no tienen correspondencia con B. Tantos LEFT OUTER JOIN pueden producirte esos valores a null que está mostrando tu tabla.

Comment: Por otro lado, recuerda que escribir todo mayúsculas se considera que estás gritando. Por favor, edita el título y el cuerpo de tu pregunta adecuadamente